# Dealing with IDs with blank spaces (Cytoscape.js)

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm implementing a prerequisite graph using Cytoscape.js.
But the problem is, when I set the id with the course name, (for example: Beginning Programming), I can't properly select the node because of the blank space in the course name.

```
temp.group = "nodes";
temp.data = {id: a, label: b}; // A: "Beginning Programming" B: "1111"
cy.add(temp);
```

Then, when I do this:

```
cy.$("Beginning Programming");
```

It says it is an invalid selector.

Is there a way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours of researching, I found that attribute selector works.
The following code works like a charm.

```
cy.$("[id='Beginning Programming']");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use spaces in the id (see [Can a DOM element have an ID that contains a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391802/can-a-dom-element-have-an-id-that-contains-a-space)).

I'd recommend replacing the space with underscore like this

```
var modifiedId = a.split(' ').join('_');
temp.data = {id: modifiedId , label: b}; // A: "Beginning_Programming" B: "1111"
```

If the id is also displayed, you could replace it with %20 (which is displayed as a space in html)

Comment: Replacing the space with underscore is another solution, but I use the id as the label too. It means I need another attribute to put the course name.