# Celsius conversion

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a homework packet for school and I don't know how to fix this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

It's a simple problem, all I have to do is convert celcius to fahrenheit.

HTML

```
<body>
    <h3>Enter the temperature in celcius</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Temp in celcius<input type="text" id="celcius" />
    </ul>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="convert" onclick="converter()"/>
    </div>
    <span id="conversion result"></span>

    <div id="tempConverter"></div>
    <span id="celciusT"></span>
    <script src="../js/JavaScript.js"></script>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
function converter() {
    var celcius = document.getElementById('celcius');
    var conversionResult = document.getElementById('conversionResult');

    conversionResult.textContent = celcius.value * 9 / 5 + 32;

}
```

Comment: This can't be all your code, I don't see `.addEventListener()` anywhere.

Comment: `addEventListener` must be in code you **haven't** posted - try line 37

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107125/cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null)

Comment: Be aware:
`document.getElementById('conversionResult');` will throw an error because your div in the html has a wrong id.

Comment: In html document there are some typos, at line 4 must be `></li>` instead of `/>` and at line 7 to close the input tag you must use `>` istead of `/>`.
Also if `document.getElementById` doesn't match a id tag that really exists in html document, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you're referencing a non-existent ID. Your HTML element has an illegal space in the ID:

```
<span id="conversion result"></span>
```

while your script uses camelCase to refer to the ID:

```
var conversionResult = document.getElementById('conversionResult');
```

I recommend picking a convention and sticking to it. I strongly discourage using camelCase for IDs (you can use it for JS if you want though). Hyphen-separated names are the most common convention, while underscore-separated names are also a valid approach.

Check out: [Google HTML/CSS Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html) and [BEM](http://getbem.com/)

---

Using spaces in IDs will only lead to trouble. Check out the [HTML 4.0 specification for basic types](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

---

StackOverflow questions:

- [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)
- [Can a DOM element have an ID that contains a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391802/can-a-dom-element-have-an-id-that-contains-a-space)