# PHP simple HTML DOM parser with spaces

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. I am capturing the text between certain div tags using

```
$html->find(div.divname)
```

This works fine until the `divname` has a space in it.

I have tried [div name] and "div name", but, neither work. How would you work with the spaces?

Comment: How about ["div name"]?

Comment: Share an example of HTML file you want to parse.

Comment: ["div name"] doesn't work 

Comment: I am trying to get into <div class="mod mod-nsbnewsdetails"> is that what you meant?

Comment: Using the dot you mean a class? A class cannot have a spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think that with `$html->find(div.divname)` you mean `$html->find('div.divname')` ...

The the divname part reflects the div's class name, not its name.

DOM element names actually [may not contain spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391802/can-a-dom-element-have-an-id-that-contains-a-space). Neither may their class names, as a space has a very different meaning there.

Technically you can do something like `$html->find('div[name=foo bar]')` for the name. Or `$html->find('div[class=foo bar]')` for the class name. But this will treat your attribute as literal, and will not cascade class names. So this is very bad practice and you shouldn't do it.