# Jquery doesn't acces table row by its ID

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this `td` "named dynamically":

```
@foreach (var m in Model)
{
    <td id="mod @m.codFilial" style="width:auto;">@m.mod</td>
}
```

As you can see, its ID is named after the value on the `foreach`, prefixed by  `"mod "`.

However, I can't seem to have access to each `td` through jquery:

```
<script>
    $("mod #@m.codFilial").append("<p>Text to append.</p>");
</script>
```

I mean, the text isn't been appended, probably because it's not recognizing the element. Am I misleading the syntax or some logic feature?

Comment: I'd recommend you to remove the space from the ID element. Also, it should be `$("#mod @m.codFilial")` instead of `$("mod #@m.codFilial")`

Comment: Thank you a lot, guys. The problem was really the space between those parts, I wasn't acceptable as a character for name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use space,@ in selector

```
<td id="mod @m.codFilial"
```

use

```
<td id="mod_m.codFilial"
```

because js will identify child of tag 'mod' where have id '@m.codFilial' if you use it

and in js

```
$("#mod_m.codFilial").append("<p>Text to append.</p>");
```

Comment: sorry dong use @  ucan chage with _ or .(dot)  for id like  mod_m.codFilial <td id="mod_m.codFilial"

Answer (score 2):

Element ids cannot contain spaces, see e.g. *[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1391810/1220550)* for details.

You could use e.g. an underscore instead of a space:

```
@foreach (var m in Model)
{
    <td id="mod_@m.codFilial" style="width:auto;">@m.mod</td>
}
```

Last but not least, in the jQuery selector you need to start with the `#` character in order to use the entire id.

```
<script>
    $("#mod_@m.codFilial").append("<p>Text to append.</p>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)